# How To Link To YouTube Video In Expanded View And Choose Desired Definition To Play In?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

I want to link to YouTube video that will **expand** itself when user lands on page and selects **appropriate** definition to play video. For example i want to link to video that can play in 240, 360, 460 and 720 definition. How can i do that?

`&fmt=18, &fmt=22` - none of these work today like they used to.

I know about `watch_popup` but it expands video to full screen and i want regular expand.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the best YouTube supports is specifying that you want HD (720p) if available. That's accomplished by appending `&hd=1` to the URL.

Almost a year ago, someone asked [pretty much the same question](https://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=5a410cf5eda20889&hl=en) on the YouTube support forum and got "Thanks for bringing this to our attention; we are looking at how to resolve this, and I will update you accordingly." from a Google employee, but I can't find any evidence that a fix has been released since then.